# Как отправить текст элемента tableview на другой коннтроллер?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Я сделал tableview с двумя stackview, в которых есть текст который берется из json
Я хочу при нажатии передавать текст, того stackview на который тапнул
Вот как выглядит таблица, допустим я нажал на 1 ячейку и хочу чтобы через prepare передавался текст именно этой ячейки. Как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Зависит от того как вы переходите на новый viewController, через segue или present

Comment: Да, чеерез segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе, это несложно, и можно сделать несколькими способами.

Вариант 1 (переход через тап по отдельному контролу на ячейке). Сначала в `cellForRowAtIndexPath` вам надо добавить хэндлер, который будет отвечать за переход (т.е вызывать `performSegue`). Т.е если у вас переход по нажатию на кнопку на ячейке, то добавляете там что-то вроде:

```
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(navigateToSecondView(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Далее в этом методе определяете ячейку:

```
let cell = sender.superview as? YourCustomTableViewCell // каст может сильно отличаться, в зависимости от того, как у вас расположены контролы в ячейке.
```

Либо вариант 2 (переход по тапу по всей ячейке).
Цепляетесь к всей ячейке вместо отдельного контрола

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as YourCustomTableViewCell
}
```

Дальше для обоих случаев вызываете self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondView", sender: cell)

И вытаскиваете в `prepareForSegue` из ее контролов весь текст, который вам нужен. Дальше логика передачи данных такая же, как обычно. Во втором ViewController создаете поле для нужных данных, берете destinationVC и передаете текст туда.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
    let cell = sender as? YourCustomTableViewCell
    destinationVC.passableText = cell.passableText // тот текст, который вам нужен.
    }
}
```